# How do I format a method for a SQL query that retrieves 0 rows?

Tags: java, sql

I'm currently trying to retrieve a list of `appointments` that occurs in the next 15 minutes by querying the `User_ID`.
The query I'm using :

```
SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE User_ID = ? and Start BETWEEN NOW() AND ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

How do I implement, that if it returns any appointments it will be `true` and if it returns 0 rows, it will be `false`?

I currently have written

```
public static boolean checkUpcomingAppointments(int userID) {
    try {
        String sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE User_ID = ? and Start BETWEEN NOW() AND ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);";
        PreparedStatement ps = JDBC.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlCheck);
        ps.setInt(1, userID);
        ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change "select *" to "select count(*)" and use
`Prepared statement.executeQuery()` instead of
`Prepared statement execute()`

Then the return value will be a ResultSet, from which you can get the count.

```
String sqlCheck = "SELECT count(*) FROM appointments WHERE User_ID = ? and Start BETWEEN NOW() AND ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);";     
   
PreparedStatement ps = JDBC.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlCheck);    

ps.setInt(1, userID);        

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();    

rs.next();

return rs.getInt(1) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()), you have this :

> `boolean execute() throws SQLException`
> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may be any kind of SQL statement. Some
> prepared statements return multiple results; the execute method
> handles these complex statements as well as the simpler form of
> statements handled by the methods executeQuery and executeUpdate. The
> execute method returns a boolean to indicate the form of the first
> result. You must call either the method getResultSet or getUpdateCount
> to retrieve the result; you must call getMoreResults to move to any
> subsequent result(s).
>
> `Returns:` true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if the
> first result is an update count or there is no result

Here you your method could look like this :

```
public static boolean checkUpcomingAppointments(int userID) {
    boolean isResultPresent = false;
    try {
        String sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE User_ID = ? and Start BETWEEN NOW() AND ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);";
        PreparedStatement ps = JDBC.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlCheck);
        ps.setInt(1, userID);
        isResultPresent = ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isResultPresent;
}
```

You can also use a `SELECT COUNT(*)` and the call the `executeQuery()`. This [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-row-count-in-jdbc) can help you.